# Assign and print at the same time in Python

Tags: python

In Python, is there a way to assign a result to a variable and immediately print it? In other words, I am looking for a one-line equivalent to

```
a = something()
print(a)
```

(just once, not every assignment should be automatically printed).

There are REPLs, e.g. for Scala, where this happens automatically:

```
scala> val count = 1
count: Int = 1
```

Comment: Yes, but not in a sane way (other than @ScottHunter's answer, which is simply two lines separated with `;` instead of `\n`).

Comment: is `something` a class? a function?

Comment: How precise are you looking for here? At the lowest level, a `syscall` to print (essentially what's happening when you `print()`) something can't be done at the same time changing a value (setting your variable) is done.

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place? I think this might be somewhat XY problem, what's wrong with the two line solution?

Comment: This is just because I find myself writing this combination a lot. I wondered whether there was a shorter way.

Comment: Some context: this is a relatively common technique in R, where it can be done by putting parens around the assignment, e.g. `(x = 1)` prints and assigns `x`. So folks coming from R, and especially using Python interactively like in Jupyter, may expect and benefit from this. But in any case seems not to be supported in any non-hacky way.

Answer (score 7):

As of `Python 3.8`, the answer to this has changed.

Now, you can assign a value to a variable and return that same value using "assignment expressions" (colloquially called "the Walrus operator").

So, this is valid Python:

```
print("Hello, {}".format((w := "world"))
```

Which will print `"Hello, world"` and assign the string `"world"` to the variable `"w"` all in one line.

Comment: good job......!

Answer (score 4):

Technically, this is one line:

```
a = something(); print(a)
```

Comment: Given the question's ambiguity, this seems like a reasonable-enough answer to me

Comment: why the down votes? This is a valid answer, and the question is not the clearest i ever read

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you just want to create a new variable and print the value of that variable like you've shown us, you could have a simple function to print and return the value:

```
def print_and_return(value):
    print(value)
    return value
```

And now you can use it like this:

```
>>> a = print_and_return(5)
5
>>> print(a)
5
```

---

An other way, which you should never use, is to use the `globals()` dict.

## I repeat, you should never do this.

```
def print_and_set(name, value):
    globals()[name] = value
    print(globals()[name])
```

Now you can call it using:

```
print_and_set('a', 5)
```

And it will print `5` and you can also access the variable `a` in the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

As of 3.8 (https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) there is a new operator known as “the walrus operator”, with this you could make a one liner.

```
print(a := something())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is missing from python and for a good reason i guess. In C  you could have a valid statement like 

`if a=30 { ... }` 

because any assignment statement would have the assigned value , which could lead someone seeing the code for the first time scratching their heads.

Also, baking your own assign function would be problematic since you get a reference copy inside the function body and not the actual variable

TL;DR; -> no, there isn't

Answer (score -1):

Technically you can "print" and assign on the same line by using sys.
See the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = sys.stdout.write("hello")
hello
>>> print(a)
5
```

As you can see, you "print" - by writing to standard out which is essentially the the same as print() - the string and assign the length of the string to the variable - not the string itself.